# Facebook like button: hide text

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I just added a Facebook like button to my website, just the most basic one, but you can't select to hide the "Sign Up to see what your friends like." text.

Because the area for the button is so small, I don't want this text, as it overlaps with other text next to it.

Is there a way to hide this part?
I basically just want the like button, with the same functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add layout="simple" (XFBML), or "data-layout"="simple" for HTML5 to the tag.

That'll show just a like button, with no count, faces or nonsense :)

Comment: Do you know if this is also possible with the iframe method?
I tried send=false&amp;layout=simple&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light, but this still gives me the text on the right of the button. (It appears it uses the 'standard' layout)

Comment: It looks like this isn't working any more... Wrapping the button in a div with width and height set, and display:none is maybe the best option. I'll look into it!

Comment: So, I can still get it to work with XFBML, but it doesn't appear to work with iframes...

Comment: I didn't test it with XFMBL as using an iframe was used here already.
But setting a fixed width and using overflow: hidden, seems to 'solve' it

Answer (score 6):

You would have probably figured it out by now but for others who haven't and reach this question, try data-layout="button_count".

You can play around here for more options: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/